# What are the trade-offs of Object vs ? in generic parameters?

Tags: java, generics

I saw some code using `Object` instead of wildcard (`?`) as a parameter of a generic class. That leads to explicit casts in the client code. What are the benefits, resp. trade-offs for such an approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `Object` as the type parameter is entirely different from using `?`. See these 2 methods:

```
void frobnicate1(List<?> someList);
void frobnicate2(List<Object> someList);
```

Both will receive a `List` and both will receive `Object` when they get an element from the `List` **but** `frobnicate1` can be called with a `List<String>` or even a `List<?>`, while `frobnicate2` can **only** be called by a `List<Object>` (or `null`).

Note, that instantiating a parameterized type can't be done with a wildcard type argument (`?`).

So the following will **not work**:

```
List<?> someList = new ArrayList<?>();
```

You will have to use `Object` (or any other non-wildcard type) instead:

```
List<?> someList = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

And don't worry about the explicit cast: The JVM can optimize it away (and probably will), since casts of any reference value to `Object` will always succeed.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. Just to be clear, I should use `frobnicate2` when I want to accept the `null` as well?

Comment: @Gabriel: **both** versions will accept `null`. The only advantage of `frobnicate2` is that you can *add* objects to the `List`, because it is defined to accept all `Object`s.

Comment: Thank you one more time, that was the answer I was looking for i nthe first place.

Answer (score 3):

I find it helpful to remember it this way:

List<Object> = a list where each element is treated as an instance of `Object`

List<?> = a list where each element is treated as a specific but unknown subclass of `Object`